# Sharing folder across network

Tags: linux, centos, samba, network-share

I have 10 linux servers and i would like to set a folder in one of the boxes for shared access.

1 server will contain files and I want 9 of the other servers to be able to read from and write to the folder that i share on this box.

Should I look into samba? is there an easy way, like how we do in windows just by sharing a folder and it s accessible for everyone after configuring it.

What should i look into? what s the right direction?

Answer (score 3):

NFS is an old and stable filesharing solution for linux and unix. 
check [this howto](http://nfs.sourceforge.net/nfs-howto/) for more info